# php preg_match partial matching

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to parse a string into components.  My solution works for full strings, but I want to be able to account for strings with potentially fewer components.  For instance, I want to be able to match `G02F   1/1335`, `G02F   1`, `G02F`, etc.  With preg_match, if not all the capturing groups match, the entire output is invalid.

```
$string = 'G02F   1/1335';
$string = strtoupper(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string));
preg_match('%^([A-H])([0-9]{1,2})([A-Z])([0-9]{1,4})/([0-9]{1,6})$%', $string, $parsed);
```

Comment: You can make symbols or match groups optional with `?`

Comment: then take out the `^ and $`, which forces the regex to use the entire string.

Comment: Do you need to extract something particular from the string or only to check the format?

Comment: I need to extract each letter or number group from the string.  It's a five level classification code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mario suggested in comment, make subpatterns optional with `?`:

```
preg_match( '%^([A-H])(\d{1,2})([A-Z])\s*(\d{1,4})?/?(\d{1,6})?$%', $string, $parsed );
```

Comment: This is great so far.  Is there a way to only accept a field if it follows a previous valid field?  For example, `G02F 1` is valid, but `GF/1335` is invalid.

Comment: There are no matches for code like `GF/1335`, there are matches for code like `G02F/1335` and since fourth part is missing in subject ( but is optional in pattern ) that item in `matches` array exists and is empty. You can check the  `matches` array for empty items to be sure that all parts are there.